# android setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE) not work in WebView @JavascriptInterface Function

Tags: java, android, android-studio

activity_main.xml content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/ny_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ny_sms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"></LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java content

```
package com......;

import android.Manifest;
import android.blablabla.and.other.imports;
...
...

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static WebView mWebView;
    static LinearLayout ny_sms;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ny_sms =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ny_sms);
        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.ny_web_view);

        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/main.html");
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this),"Android");
   }

    public static void showLayoutMA() {
        mWebView.setVisibility(WebView.INVISIBLE);
        ny_sms.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    }
}

class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showLayout() {
        MainActivity.showLayoutMA();
    }
}
```

main.html content

```
<html>
  <body>
    <center>
      <a href="#" onclick="Android.showLayout()">Visiblity Test</a>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

all permissions ok. al settings ok, app version 28 (android 9 pie)

im click "Visiblity Test" link not change any screen activity, 
and after scroll to bottom nofication top bar click toggle auto rotate screen button
auto refresh and show LinearLayout front of the webview control.

how to fix this problem.

not showing LinearLayout and webView not invisible with "Visiblity Test" clicked. after need a refreshing action.

Sorry my English is bad :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im found this problem,
returned error "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"

So then you need me: runOnUiThread()

extend this code...

```
public static void showLayoutMA() {
    CurrentActivitiy.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //mWebView.setVisibility(WebView.INVISIBLE);
        ny_sms.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

why not use direct runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {} function, because my function is static, im add "CurrentActivitiy" declaration of MainActivity.

```
static Activity CurrentActivitiy;
CurrentActivitiy = (Activity)MainActivity.this;
```

and after few hours happy ending, problem is resolved..